# Jquery page reload error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, reload

I am working on a messaging PHP script. In order to view users their message i am trying to reload DIV so that i should be real-time. I have two page one is where the number of new message is shown:

```
 <?php 
     include ('config.php')
     ?>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script>
      var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
     $('#xxxx').fadeOut('slow', function() {
       $(this).load('message.php', function() {
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
         });
        });
        }, 40000); 

       </script>

            <div id="xxxx"><?php include ('yahu.php') ?></div>
```

And other page shows the reload result:

```
<?php
     include ('config.php');
     $nb_new_pm = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select count(*) as nb_new_pm from pm                   where ((user1="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and user1read="no") or  (user2="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and user2read="no")) and id2="1"'));
        $nb_new_pm = $nb_new_pm['nb_new_pm'];
         if ($nb_new_pm == 0)
          {
          }
         else
          {
           ?>
          <font color="black">You have got <?php echo $nb_new_pm; ?> new message&#40;s&#41;.</font>
    <?php
       }
      ?>
```

Firstly, it worked really well. But when the page reloads it only show value of
"nb_new_pm" and it also changes it's colour to white.
Please Help Me!!!!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Did you try checking out existing messaging systems? Google for it and learn from the existing. Try not to reinvent the wheel...

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things scream out here.

1. You need to look at using PDO rather than the MySQL calls that you are making.
2. Look at returning JSON objects which your client side JQuery can then output.
3. To extend point two, why not try and show the actual message? rather than a count.
4. You *could* look into something like web sockets for this.
5. And lastly if your not stuck on PHP take a look at Socket.io as an option.

Hope this helps a little and good luck!